# I'm confused about boundary conditions and walls in thermal simulation (using IcePak)

Tags: thermal

I'm trying to learn a little thermal simulation. I just have a single LED on a board, I made a 3d model for it. And I thought I could use thermal simulation to see how big I need to make the board to give it enough of a heatsink so the LED won't overheat (natural convection only). I got pretty far but I get confused about setting up the walls. As I understand it now the wall is any interface between my LED board and the air so if I set a wall at the top of the PCB (a) below and put in 100mW it raises the temp to 92C. Then I thought well, might as well include the dome of the LED and the sides of the LED in this simulation too. So I assigned a wall to the dome at (b) too

But! When I did that my temperatures leapt up to 260C. So then I realized I probably don't understand what I'm doing with the walls here. Does anyone have any experience setting this up properly? I feel like I'm missing some key point here about the boundary conditions.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with *Electrical* Engineering.

Comment: @brhans Thermal considerations are a very important part of electrical engineering. It's why things go poof.

Comment: Thermal considerations for dissipation are absolutely on-topic here.  This is very much an electrical engineering topic.